Generate grpc java client
I am trying to compile my proto into a grpc java client and a python grpc java server.
I can't get the java generated class to produce the Services.
The following is proto named 'myproto.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

package amat.metrology_setup.api.services.generic_measurement;
option java_package  = "amat.metrology_setup.api.services.generic_measurement";

message AlLData {
  map<string, SingleData> map_data = 1;
}
message SingleData{
  map<string, string> params = 1;
}
message Empty{

}
service Updaer {
  rpc SendData(AlLData) returns (Empty);
  rpc GetUpdatedData(Empty) returns (AlLData);
}

Python works well, but the java cannot geneate the matching Updaer.
I've read that without the protoc-gen-grpc-java plugin it is expected not to generate services.
Like this:
$protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/my_proto.proto

I know that I need grpc pluginprotoc-gen-grpc-java to generate the services and that wit
So i've done:
$protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=$grpc_java_plugin $proto_file

But I still can't get the services to be compiled. All the paths are valid because the file is being compiled.
what am I missing?

Not a Java dev. It is confusing. Usually with Java, Maven or Gradle are used to build the stubs but you should be able to use protoc too. Although you've specified the plugin protoc-gen-grpc-java, you've not included the flag that effects it, you will need to add something like --grpc-java_out=${DST_DIR} (the plugin omitting the protoc-gen- and with _out (there may additionally be an _opt too).

I've now tried using your flag and it still wouldn't get generated.

Which build tool are you using for building your java project? is it gradle or maven?

I am trying solo, with protoc. I've tried utilzing the existing gradle but that's a complex system here.

I'm running Linux AMD64 and:

created your myproto.proto (including the typo in the service name Updaer) and;
downloaded protoc-gen-grpc-java from Maven.
ran protoc1 command as described in the comments


1 As mentioned, for Java, protoc is commonly invoked using Maven, Gradle ...

ARCH="linux-x86_64"
VERS="1.64.0"

PLUGIN="protoc-gen-grpc-java-${VERS}-${ARCH}.exe"

wget \
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/${VERS}/${PLUGIN}

chmod +x ${PLUGIN}

Before:
.
├── myproto.proto
└── protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.64.0-linux-x86_64.exe

Then, I used the command as I described in the comment:
protoc \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=${PLUGIN} \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--java_out=${PWD} \
--grpc-java_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/myproto.proto

After:
.
├── amat
│   └── metrology_setup
│       └── api
│           └── services
│               └── generic_measurement
│                   ├── Myproto.java
│                   └── UpdaerGrpc.java
├── myproto.proto
└── protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.64.0-linux-x86_64.exe

